# Google Analytics code, how does it work?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

From here:
http://www.google.com/support/analyticshelp/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1136920

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function recordOutboundLink(link, category, action) {
  try {
    var myTracker=_gat._getTrackerByName();
    _gaq.push(['myTracker._trackEvent', ' + category + ', ' + action + ']);
    setTimeout('document.location = "' + link.href + '"', 100)
  }catch(err){}
}
</script>
```

If you notice the + category + and + action + are in quotes. So how does the analytics script gets their values?

Comment: More than likely the string being passed in gets eval'd.

Comment: can it be evaled in another function's context?

Comment: here's an example, http://jsfiddle.net/uEqkC/

Comment: In your example, category and action are on the same function as the eval. While the analytics code, if there is an eval, it's outside of the scope where category and action are defined

Comment: You're right... it would be out of scope. That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

It's a mistake in their documentation; their code will not work as intended.

That line should read:

```
_gaq.push(['myTracker._trackEvent',  category ,  action ]);
```

You're right. The way they have it, it has category and action passed as literal strings, rather than passing the variables that hold the strings in them.

Comment: The reason I asked was that analytics event tracking was not working. I will see if this code works. Thanks.